# How to select the second paragraph?

Tags: jquery, css

Like for example:
Suppose I want to give color to the second paragraph.

```
<div class="intro">
    <p>My name is Donald</p>
    <p>I live in Duckburg</p>
    <p>I have many friends:</p>
</div>
```

How can I only Select the second paragraph in CSS as well as jQuery as no name or ids are assigned two them.

Comment: In CSS use `:nth-child(2)`, in jQuery use `eq(1)`

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/szq7onru/

Comment: @Rory - `.intro p:nth-of-type(2)`, _not_ `.intro p:nth-child(2)` (!) Otherwise subsequent revisions of the document (eg. inserting an `img` between the first and second paragraphs) will mean the style no longer works, because the second child will no longer be a `p`.

Comment: Well yes. There's an infinite number of ways to change the solution if you want to invent new HTML markup. All I can do is give an answer based on what the OP has shown.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$(".intro p:nth-child(2)");
// OR
$(".intro p:eq(2)");
```

See Code Block below:

```js
$(".intro p:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "red");
// OR
// $(".intro p:eq(1)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
    <p>My name is Donald</p>
    <p>I live in Duckburg</p>
    <p>I have many friends:</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: eq() starts at 0 so with eq(2), you are actually selecting the 3rd child

Comment: Ya you are right, I've updated the answer...

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for CSS:

```
.intro p:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue; 
}
```

It'll pick only the second paragraph and add blue color to it